# How to disable left, right, top and bottom drop targets in AvalonDock 2(LayoutDocumentPane)

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I'm trying to disable drop targets except the center one in avalon dock. Couldn't find any documentation to do that in codeplex. I found one similar question in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422972/disable-drop-targets-layouts-in-avalondock) but no correct response so asking again.

Comment: [Answered the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43326676/3895469)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option, you can override OverlayWindow control style and remove or change drop areas from it:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type avalonDockControls:OverlayWindow}"
     TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:OverlayWindow}">
...
        <Grid x:Name="PART_AnchorablePaneDropTargets">
          <Grid Width="88"
                Height="88"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   Grid.RowSpan="3"
                   Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/DockPaneEmpty.PNG"
                   Stretch="Uniform">
            </Image>
            <Border Name="PART_AnchorablePaneDropTargetTop"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockPaneTop.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="PART_AnchorablePaneDropTargetRight"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Grid.Row="1">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockPaneRight.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="PART_AnchorablePaneDropTargetBottom"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockPaneBottom.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="PART_AnchorablePaneDropTargetLeft"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="1">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockPaneLeft.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="PART_AnchorablePaneDropTargetInto"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockPaneInside.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="PART_DocumentPaneDropTargets">
          <Grid Width="88"
                Height="88"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   Grid.RowSpan="3"
                   Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/DockPaneEmpty.PNG"
                   Stretch="Uniform">
            </Image>
            <Border Name="PART_DocumentPaneDropTargetTop"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockDocPaneTop.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="PART_DocumentPaneDropTargetRight"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Grid.Row="1">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockDocPaneRight.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="PART_DocumentPaneDropTargetBottom"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockDocPaneBottom.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="PART_DocumentPaneDropTargetLeft"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="1">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockDocPaneLeft.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
            <Border Name="PART_DocumentPaneDropTargetInto"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1">
              <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/InnerDockPaneInside.png"
                     Stretch="None">
              </Image>
            </Border>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Canvas>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The elements you will need to change have "DropTarget" in their names.
Full version of style is here: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/Themes/generic.xaml starting from line 479.